# How to get the value of a checkbox item in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have three checkbox items

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my_list" value="val 1">
<input type="checkbox" name="my_list" value="val 2">
<input type="checkbox" name="my_list" value="val 3">
```

What I want to be able to do in angular is when I click a box, e.g. "val 2"

```
my_list.value    // yields 'val 2'
my_list.checked  // yields true or false depending on if it's checked or not
```

The problem is that

```
 my_list.value
```

returns true or false, which is not what I want. I want it to return what I have in the 'value' attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-true-value` like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my_list" ng-model="my_list" ng-true-value="val 1">
<input type="checkbox" name="my_list" ng-model="my_list" ng-true-value="val 2">
<input type="checkbox" name="my_list" ng-model="my_list" ng-true-value="val 3">
```

`{{my_list}}` will then be empty if nothing is checked, and show "val 1" if the first checkbox is checked, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Checkbox is a multiple-choice input so each of them should have its own name (or rather: `ng-model`). If you want a single-choice input, you sholud use **radio**:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="val 1" />
<input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="val 2" />
```

And now, `{{value}}` will be evaluated to `val 1` or `val 2`, according to selection.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I asked for. I need to build a list whose values are the values of the checkboxes. That way if I check a box, I know to use the value, otherwise not. I'd be happy to accept your answer if you can answer my posted question. :)

Comment: Only way I can think of is declaring `$scope.value = []` in your controller, binding checkboxes to `value[0]`, `value[1]` etc. and then removing nulls form `value` (for example using Underscore: `_.without(value,null)`).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys but I solved it myself.

I use a checkbox like this :

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="Added Items" ng-change="checkbox_change('my_list1', 'val 1')" ng-model="my_list1" value="val 1">
```

The arguments specify 
  1. Which model to access.
  2. The the value of the checkbox.

I then use this function

```
      $scope.checkbox_change = function(key, val) {
        alert($scope[key]);
        alert(val);
      }
```

Which allows me to access the model and the value of the checkbox.